# Java GC - Understanding TargetSurivorRatio

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Having a GC problem that I can't seem to fix and hoping someone can provide some insight. The real fix would be to add additional JVM's to accommodate the load, but that's out of my power for the time being.

My question is if someone could explain the nuances of `-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio`

From the description:

> If the application being fine-tuned has a relatively consistent object allocation rate, it is acceptable to raise the target survivor occupancy to something as high as -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80 or -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90. The advantage of being able to do so helps reduce the amount of survivor space needed to age objects. The challenge with setting -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio= higher is the HotSpot VM not being able to better adapt object aging in the presence of spikes in object allocation rates, which can lead to tenuring objects sooner than you would like

Spikes in object allocation rates is exactly what I'm suffering from, as shown below:
`2015-07-07T15:24:56.592-0500: 2760.113: [GC 2760.113: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 483183816 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 5)
- age   1:  105182048 bytes,  105182048 total
- age   2:     220512 bytes,  105402560 total
- age   3:     292176 bytes,  105694736 total
- age   4:     303792 bytes,  105998528 total
- age   5:     494584 bytes,  106493112 total
: 3155059K->104104K(3670016K), 0.1605850 secs] 10036522K->6986163K(15204352K), 0.1611320 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs]
2015-07-07T15:25:06.838-0500: 2770.359: [GC 2770.359: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 483183816 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 5)
- age   1:  405021040 bytes,  405021040 total
- age   2:     114464 bytes,  405135504 total
- age   3:     175872 bytes,  405311376 total
- age   4:     292176 bytes,  405603552 total
- age   5:     302512 bytes,  405906064 total
: 3249821K->398565K(3670016K), 0.1744060 secs] 10131880K->7281107K(15204352K), 0.1747200 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs]
2015-07-07T15:25:14.251-0500: 2777.772: [GC 2777.772: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 483183816 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 5)
- age   1:  536174616 bytes,  536174616 total
- age   2:     202152 bytes,  536376768 total
- age   3:      66784 bytes,  536443552 total
- age   4:     175440 bytes,  536618992 total
- age   5:     292176 bytes,  536911168 total
: 3544293K->524288K(3670016K), 1.3915370 secs] 10426835K->8124824K(15204352K), 1.3919310 secs] [Times: user=2.70 sys=0.00, real=1.40 secs]
2015-07-07T15:25:24.958-0500: 2788.479: [GC 2788.479: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 483183816 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 5)
- age   1:    9526032 bytes,    9526032 total
: 3670016K->155222K(3670016K), 0.3542590 secs] 11270552K->7846132K(15204352K), 0.3546270 secs] [Times: user=0.67 sys=0.01, real=0.36 secs]`

My JAVA_OPTS are as follows:

`-Xms15360M 
    -Xmx15360M
    -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
    -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
    -verbose:gc
    -XX:+PrintGCDetails
    -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
    -Xloggc:logs/gc.log
    -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
    -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=65
    -XX:NewSize=4096M
    -XX:MaxNewSize=4096M
    -XX:SurvivorRatio=6
    -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
    -XX:PermSize=512M
    -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
    -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
    -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
    -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=5
    -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90`

I've been decreasing the SurvivorRatio (increasing available Survivor Space), and increasing NewSize proportionally, but it seems that no matter what I do, my spikes are always 20-80 MB greater than my Survivor Space and I continue to promote garbage.

Back to the question at hand.. Would decreasing TargetSurvivorRatio help my spikes? And if so how? Wouldn't setting it to 50% decrease my available Survivor Space drastically, causing me to prematurely promote more often? And any other input you have as to how I can survive the first highly-allocated collection would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

> UPDATE

After hours of reading into it, as well as the days I spent researching prior to posting, I think I finally landed on a conclusion to my question. `TargetSurvivorRatio=90` is a good setting for my use-case. In order to set the memory usage of the survivor space close to the TargetRatio, the JVM will dynamically choose a tenuring threshold (limited by MaxTenuring, of course) in order to meet the desired goal.

In my case, objects are more or less tenured after age 4, and very small. Accommodating Age: 1 is my top priority -- Extremely large number of surviving objects that don't live to see Age: 2. I need as much survivor space available as possible, since I have an already over-sized JVM, limited space in the Old Gen, and no ability to assign additional heap. My use-case is not a "spike in object allocation rates", as I thought the option was referring to... It's just one massive spike.

Where a lower Target Ratio would be beneficial are scenarios where the MaxTenuringThreshold is set to a high number, and carries a steady amount of tenured objects all the way through. If an increased number of newly tenured objects survive, and the TargetRatio is set too high, the JVM will be unable to adjust the Tenuring Threshold to prevent premature promotion.

As to an overall fix to my problem.. increasing survivor size by lowering the ratio and/or increasing the young gen size